# HTMLPurifier removes target="_blank"

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I'm using HTMLPurifier and even thou I have :

```
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
```

it removes all 'target' attribues from the links.

Any idea why is it doing it?

Comment: [Sure you got the latest purifier](http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/ticket/1700)? Also, sure your HTML is valid? :)

Comment: Yes - all valid and version downloaded yesterday.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [list of allowed frame targets](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Attr.AllowedFrameTargets) is [not enabled by default](http://groups.google.com/group/htmlpurifier/browse_thread/thread/95a5908cc9b53ad2). You have to enable it manually.

Comment: That was exactly this - I've used the following: $config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank')); and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought CKEditor was responsible for this. With YML configurations you need to define an array like this (child of html_purifier -> config):   Attr.AllowedFrameTargets: [ '_blank', '_top', '_self', '_parent' ]

Answer (score 1):

In a Yii2 application, inside of a DetailView, I configured HtmlPurifier as follows:

```
[
    'label' => 'Document PDF',
    'format'=> 'raw',
    'value' => HtmlPurifier::process(DocumentFunctions::viewDocumentPdfInView($model->document_id), [
    'Attr.AllowedFrameTargets' => ['_blank'],
    ]),
],
```

Here is a simpler way I found:

```
[
    'label' => 'Document PDF',
    'format'=> ['html', 'config' => ['Attr.AllowedFrameTargets' => ['_blank']]],
    'value' => DocumentFunctions::viewDocumentPdfInView($model->document_id),
]
```